# org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Markup not found for Component: [TreeTableItem [Component id = 0]]

Tags: java, spring, wicket, wicket-8

I am getting below error after upgrading the Wicket framework from 6.x to 8.x. Where I updated the below dependency to keep the deprecated TreeTable code in wicket 8.x.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket15-tree</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
private void myTreePage() {
    TreeTable myTestTree = new TreeTable("myTestTreeTable", new DefaultTreeModel(myTestRootNode), cols);
    statusImport();
    myTestTree.setRootLess(true);
    myTestTree.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    addOrReplace(myTestTree);
}




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <body>
        <wicket:extend>
            <div class="statusMsg"><span wicket:id="runIds"></span></div>
            <div class="query_table_header"><label>Import Table</label></div>
            <div wicket:id="myTestTreeTable"></div>
            <form wicket:id="form">
                <div wicket:id="countFilter">
                     <div class="query_table_header"><label>status</label></div>
                </div>
                <div><label>Entity: </label> <select wicket:id="selectEntity"/> <label>Status: </label> <select wicket:id="selectStatus"/></div>
            <input type="submit" value="select" wicket:id="select"/> <input type="submit" wicket:id="bucket" value="Start Reprocessing" />
            </form>
        </wicket:extend>
    </body>
</html>
```

As I found if I remove the tag  then page is loading without any error. I think here issue is looking with the tag placement or tag definition.

---

> ERROR | Exception occured:
> org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Markup not found for Component: [TreeTableItem [Component id = 0]]
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2267)
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2227)
> at org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.tree.table.MiddleColumnsView.onRender(MiddleColumnsView.java:189)
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2296)
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2227)
> at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1454)
> at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1654)
> at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1629)
> at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:798)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:77)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112)
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2491)
> at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1593)
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2296)
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2227)
> at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1454)
> at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1654)
> at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:858)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onRender(WebPage.java:126)
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2296)
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2227)
> at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:998)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:124)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:236)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:202)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:914)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:282)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
> at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:275)
> at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:206)
> at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:299)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:204)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunn

Comment: Which version of wicket15-tree do you use now ? It should be 8.0.0

Comment: Yes @martin-g using this version "8.0.0" but still getting this error.

Comment: Can anyone suggest any solution on this issue, it can help me to resolve my current issues in the application.

Comment: Please create a demo project at GitHub and we can take a look!

Comment: Hi @martin-g, As per my findings issue is with the tag of this wicket Id "myTestTreeTable". I mentioned the HTML code in the question. 

I am able to load the page without any error if I remove this ID from the HTML page. Kindly let me know if it can help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi @martin-g, I have resolved this issue and posted the answer in this post. But I am facing one more issue here that table column name in the HTML page is not displaying. I tried a lot of things but column names are not displaying in the table. 

Can you please suggest any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the exception after replacing TreeTable class to TableTree class.

Please refer to below code:

```
    private final DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("<root>");
DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);

        ITreeProvider<DefaultMutableTreeNode> modelProvider = new TreeModelProvider<DefaultMutableTreeNode>(treeModel, false) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public IModel<DefaultMutableTreeNode> model(DefaultMutableTreeNode object) {
                return Model.of(object);
            }
        };
        
        TableTree<DefaultMutableTreeNode, String> myTestTree = new TableTree<DefaultMutableTreeNode, String>("myTestTreeTable", createColumns(), modelProvider, Long.MAX_VALUE) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            protected Component newContentComponent(String id, IModel<DefaultMutableTreeNode> model) {
                //return new CheckedFolder<DefaultMutableTreeNode>(id, this, model);
                return new Folder<DefaultMutableTreeNode>(id, this, model);
            }
        };
        
        //myTestTree.getTable().addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar<>(myTestTree.getTable(), null));
        //myTestTree.getTable().addBottomToolbar(new NoRecordsToolbar(myTestTree.getTable()));
        myTestTree.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        myTestTree.add(new WindowsTheme());
        //myTestTree.setItemReuseStrategy(new ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy());
        //myTestTree.getTable().add(AttributeModifier.replace("class", "table table-striped table-condensed"));
        myTestTree.getTable().add(AttributeModifier.replace("style", "width: 100%; background-color:white;"));
        addOrReplace(myTestTree);
```

Tree table date is displaying perfectly but table column heading's name is not displaying in the page. Please refer the column creation code.

```
    private List<? extends IColumn<DefaultMutableTreeNode, String>> createColumns() {
    columns.add(new TreeColumn<>(new Model("Tree"), "obj.text"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn<>(new Model("FileStatus"), "FileStatus", "obj.fileStatus"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn<>(new Model("StartDate"), "StartDate", "obj.startDate"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn<>(new Model("LastDate"), "LastDate", "obj.lastDate"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn<>(new Model("Count"), "Count", "obj.count"));
    return columns;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am able to display the Tree table without any issue but the column's header still is not resolved to display. Columns names are "Tree", "FileStatus", "StartDate", "LastDate", "Count". Can anyone help me to resolve the issue to display these headers?